# when anaconda prompt is called it says access is denied

Tags: cmd, path, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

when i open anaconda prompt or use "conda" in cmd its says access is denied and window prompt

"
this app can't run on your pc to find a version for your pc check with the software publisher"

and right now i also cant open anaconda navigator as well

Noted: I have been using the anaconda for a while with no problem before, however i miss-clicked sign out option instead of shutdown from window10 and it seem that the privacy is changed somehow, so far i have try changing environment variable and manage app execution alias but both of them did not solve the issue. Please share your solution if you experience this before thank you

Comment: I just experienced the same right now. It was running 1 minute ago!

Comment: I just noticed `conda.exe` file has now 0 bytes. Maybe it can have a relationship with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for it is the worst possible: I simply reinstalled Anaconda.

You can also try just getting `conda.exe` from the compiled source and replace it on `Scripts` folder instead of reinstalling it.

Comment: Do you have any idea what is the cause of the issue, and getting conda from compiled source meaning building the program right?

Comment: No idea what caused it. You can look for the compiled .exe on Anaconda repository, maybe they have it. Anyway, reinstalling it is the quickest way to do it, I guess (unless it's possible to decompile the installation executable).
If this worked for you, please check as accepted solution.